# How to define a variable once in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have my code, I know the problem, I do not know how to fix it though.

My 'btc' variable is redefined whenever you load the page, making it always load as 1, how would I make btc load once, and only once for the duration of the cookie 'username's lifetime?

(I cannot add any more 'btc' to the variable, because when I refresh it, it always redefines it as one.)

```
<html>
<body onload="abu()">
<style>
.column {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 120px;
    border: 12px solid blue;
    padding: 19.5px;
    margin: 19.5px;
}
.col {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 120px;
    border: 12px solid red;
    padding: 19.5px;
    margin: 19.5px;


}
body{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.shutterstock.com/shutterstock/videos/2669351/thumb/1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ff2a00;
    color: white;
}

</style>
<center><h1>Dashboard</h1></center>
<div class="column"><p id="btc">Satoshi: 0</p></div>
<div class="col"><p id="dash">WIP</p></div>

<!---<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Payout</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>FirstSat</td>
    <td><button onclick="foo()"><img src="kop.png" width="32" height="28">Here</button></td>
    <td>1</td>


  </tr>
</table>---!>
<button onclick="testsan()">a</button>
<script>
var btc = 1;
function update()
{
    document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = "Satoshi: " + btc;
}



abu();
function testsan() {
    var username = parseInt(getCookie("username"));
    btc = btc + 1
    document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = "Satoshi: " + btc;
    setCookie("username", username + 1);

}
function abu() { 
    var username = parseInt(getCookie("username"));
    if (isNaN(username)) {
        username = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = "Satoshi: " + btc;
    setCookie("username", username + 1);


}



function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {

    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
alert('user = "' + user + '"');
       if (user != undefined) {
           setCookie("username", btc);

       }
    }
}

</script>


</html>
```

If you could help, it would be very much appreciated! ^^

Comment: If you want a value to persist across page reloads you need to keep it in a cookie, local storage, etc.

Comment: That code looks like you're randomly trying arbitrary things, without really understanding what you're doing. Take it one step at a time. localStorage example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2ce7v4sq/

Comment: Unrelated, but please only include code directly related to the question. Here a simple variable declaration would suffice-none of the rest matters and just makes the question longer for no reason. The CSS is even more useless.

Comment: That is demonstrably false: you write "var btc = 1". Where do you load it from a cookie?

Comment: @ChrisG thank you very much, I used that to make it work. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In `checkCookie`, if the user's cookie exists, retrieve the `btc` value from `localStorage` (if it exists). Otherwise, set the `btc` value to 1, both in `localStorage` and in the variable. For example, assuming you run `checkCookie` on every page load (or before the `btc` is used:

```
let btc;
function checkCookie() {
  var user=getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
    btc = Number(sessionStorage.btc || 1);
  } else {
    alert('user = "' + user + '"');
    if (user != undefined) {
      setCookie("username", btc);
    }
    btc = 1;
  }
}
```

And then in `testsan`, assign to `localStorage`:

```
function testsan() {
  btc = btc + 1;
  localStorage.btc = btc;
  // ...
```

If you also want to keep track of a separate `btc` for each user, then you'll have to make an *object* of users and `btc` values, and stringify/parse it when setting or getting `localStorage`.

Answer (score -1):

instead of setting:
`var btc = 1;`
You can use `local storage`, like so:

```
function getBtc = (is_update_btc) => {
    // to get from local storage
    let btc_start = window.localStorage.get('btc') || 1;
    // e.g.
    // if (is_update_btc) {
    //    btc_start = btc_start + 1;
    //}    
    // to set back to local storage after whatever manipulation:
    window.localStorage.set('btc', btc_start);
};

let btc = getBtc();
```

Comment: The problem is: it redefines btc as 1 every single time, no matter what I change it too, when I refresh it will stay as 1.

Comment: You asked how to define a variable once in JS? that's what I answered

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not looking for how to make a page reload.

Comment: @EladKatz Not what I was looking for still.

Comment: @asdwdwdad I didn't say you were.

Comment: When I start the page, I want btc as 1, then I can add more to it, and refresh it and it stays at the number I put it at and not 1.

Comment: what about now? @asdwdwdad ?